# Getting jQuery datepicker to attach to a TextBox within a ListView

Tags: asp.net, jquery, listview, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the jQuery Datepicker without any problem for TextBox controls that are non-templated. However, I am unable to get the datepicker to work with a TextBox that is in an EditItemTemplate of a ListView control. My latest attempt is to get a handle on this textbox by CSS class name "DateControl", any ideas?

```
<asp:ListVIew id="lvTest" runat="server">  
  <LayoutTemplate>...</LayoutTemplate>  
  <ItemTemplate>...</ItemTemplate>  
  <EditItemTemplate>  
     <tr>  
       <td>  
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpReceiveDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("exp_receive_date","{0:dd-MMM-yy}") %>' CssClass="DateControl" />  
       </td>  
     </tr>  
  </EditTemplate>  
</asp:ListView>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
   $(document).ready(function () {  
     $('.DateControl').datepick({ dateFormat: 'M-dd-yyyy' });  
   });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to just be a case where I needed to attach the datepicker to my controls inside of...

```
function pageLoad(sender, args){}
```

instead of...

```
$(document).ready(function () {});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `.` at the beginning of a class name when selecting with jQuery (just like CSS):

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  $('.DateControl').datepick({ dateFormat: 'M-dd-yyyy' });  
});
```

Comment: That was just a typo in my post, corrected now, thanks. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used a ListView, but I think that the Edit controls are exposed dynamically - there's no postback.

So in order to attach to a dynamically included element, you'll need to use the new [jquery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) - not sure if you can do something like

```
$('.DateControl').live('click', function() {
  $('.DateControl').datepick({ dateFormat: 'M-dd-yyyy' });  
});
```

or if you have to attach that to the Edit event something like:

```
$("DateControl").live("showEdit", function(e, myName, myValue){
  $('.DateControl').datepick({ dateFormat: 'M-dd-yyyy' });  
});
$("EditControl").click(function () {
  $("DataControl").trigger("showEdit");
});
```

But that should be enough to get you started.